# Failed to start the Kernel AttributeError: 'SelectIOLoop' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kernel, jupyter, tornado

I try to:
`import numpy as np`
as usual using vscode, but it Failed to start the Kernel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl88y.png)

`AttributeError: 'SelectIOLoop' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'.`
`View Jupyter log for further details.`

python version: python 3.11.1
vscode version: vscode 1.84.2

can anyone help? thank you.

i already try to re install the tornado to newest version.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your tornado version?

Answer (score 1):

AttributeError: 'SelectIOLoop' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'. View Jupyter log for further details.

You will need to upgrade your tornado version to at least 5.0 by command `pip install tornado --upgrade`